# Saving/Restoring multiple settings files in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, settings

I have 3 settings files within the Properties folder in a WinForms application. They are the default Settings, Tool, and Vehicle. Settings all work fine.

I use the following code to Export the settings from user.config:

```
internal static void Export(string settingsFilePath)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    var config = configurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    config.SaveAs(settingsFilePath);
}
```

And to restore:

```
internal static void Import(string settingsFilePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(settingsFilePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    var appSettings = Properties.Settings.Default;
    try
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
            ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

        string appSettingsXmlName = 
            Properties.Settings.Default.Context["GroupName"].ToString(); 
        // returns "MyApplication.Properties.Settings";

        // Open settings file as XML
        var import = XDocument.Load(settingsFilePath);
        // Get the whole XML inside the settings node
        var settings = import.XPathSelectElements("//" + appSettingsXmlName);

        config.GetSectionGroup("userSettings")
            .Sections[appSettingsXmlName]
            .SectionInformation
            .SetRawXml(settings.Single().ToString());
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("userSettings");

        appSettings.Reload();
    }
    catch (Exception) // Should make this more specific
    {
        // Could not import settings.
        appSettings.Reload(); // from last set saved, not defaults
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is only extract, for example, the section Properties.Vehicle.Default settings only and update user.config changing only that section of the sectionGroup "userSettings". The purpose being to save a vehicle loading its settings to be used - but not changing Settings, or Tool settings.

```
<sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <section name="Drive.Properties.Tool" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Drive.Properties.Vehicle" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Drive.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
```

However the code line:

```
config.GetSectionGroup("userSettings")
            .Sections[appSettingsXmlName]
            .SectionInformation
            .SetRawXml(settings.Single().ToString());
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Only allows me to isolate the userSettings so all the sections are loaded and overwrite the user config. I have tried the section name, but since it is not a group, the return is null.

So is there any way I can specify to extract only one of the sections from within the sectionGroup from my exported xml file and update user.config with only that section leaving the others unaffected?

I am so close - but not close enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have three settings `SettingsA.settings`, and `Settings.Settings`:

- The default values for those settings will be stored as sections of `userSettings` section group in application config file (`<YourAppName>.exe.config`) beside you application file.
- The user values of those settings will be stored as sections of `userSettingsd` section group in `user.config` file in `%userprofile%\appdata\local\<YourAppName>\<Hash>\<Version>`.
- The following code save all the current user configs into a single file, including SettingsA, and Settings. It's basically like copying the `user.config` file which contains current user values:

  ```
  ConfigurationManager
      .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
      .SaveAs(path);
  ```
- The following code will restore just `SettingsA` from a back up file that you created using above code:

  ```
  var config = ConfigurationManager
     .OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
  string sectionName = Properties.SettingsA.Default.Context["GroupName"].ToString();
  var document = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, path));
  var settingsA = document.XPathSelectElements($"//{sectionName}")
      .Single().ToString();
  config.GetSectionGroup("userSettings")
      .Sections[sectionName].SectionInformation.SetRawXml(settingsA);
  config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
  Properties.SettingsA.Default.Reload();
  ```

Comment: Don't get confused by `Setting.settings` file, it's not a special file, it's just one of the settings files, quite similar to `SettingsA.settings`

Comment: Works as requested. Thank you so much. Getting to the sectionName as selection was the trick for the document to fix only the one section in user.config

Comment: Any idea how config settings knows when to use the default settings file, or to use the config? Is it simply the fact there is a node in user.config ? It works and uses the restored setting even though the restore adds that elements to an almost empty user.config. It's a pretty clever system.

Comment: For user settings, it first looks for `user.config` file in `%userprofile%\appdata\local\<YourAppName>\<Hash>\<Version>`, then in `<YourAppName>.exe.config` beside you application file and then into the `DefaultSettingValueAttribute` of the property.